# How to send the pdf file uploaded in the contact form as an attachment to the mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Excuse me for the noob question.

I Want to send the pdf file uploaded in the contact form as an attachment to the mailer.

```
  class ContactPagesController < ApplicationController
  def new
   @contact_page =  ContactPage.new
   end

   def create
    @contact_page = ContactPage.new(contact_page_params)
   if    @contact_page.save

     contact_page = @contact_page

     ContactMailer.contact_email(contact_page).deliver_now
     flash[:notice]="we have recieved your details successfully"
     redirect_to root_path
    else

     if @contact_page.errors.any?
    flash[:notice]= "Please fill all the manditory fields"
    end
     render :new
    end
  end

  private
    def contact_page_params
      params.require(:contact_page).permit( :name, :email, :phone, :messsage, :document)
    end
  end
```

my mailer

```
    class ContactMailer < ApplicationMailer
     default to: 'sss@mail.com'


    def contact_email(contact_page)
            @contact_page = contact_page
          mail(from: 'sss@mail.com', subject: 'Recieved A Contact Enquery')
        end
       end
```

contact_email.html.erb

```
    <td ><%= @contact_page.email %></td>
    <td ><%= @contact_page.phone %></td>
    <td ><%= @contact_page.name %></td>
    <td ><%= @contact_page.messsage %></td>
```

The email is successfully triggered.How can I Send the document as an attachment to the email?

Any Help is Highly Appreciated.Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-i-attachments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
def contact_email(pdf,email,contact_page)
   @contact_page = contact_page
    mail(to: email,
    subject: "Recieved A Contact Enquery")
    mail.attachments['test.pdf'] = { mime_type: 'application/pdf;  charset=UTF-8 ;', content: pdf } 

                               OR

    mail.attachments['test.pdf'] = File.read('path/to/file.pdf')
 end
```

Comment: Thanks for your Quick response.document is a data attribute submitted in the form, which is whitelisted in the controller for every new contact form submission.

Comment: @suresh  are you store the pdf file ?

Comment: yes I'm able to save the data and pdf successfully.

Comment: @suresh Replace `def contact_email(contact_page)
   @contact_page = contact_page
    mail(to: @contact_page.email,
    subject: "Recieved A Contact Enquery")
    mail.attachments['test.pdf'] = { mime_type: 'application/pdf;  charset=UTF-8 ;', content: @contact_page.document} 
 end` replce your code with this

Comment: sorry for the noob question,  what is 'test.pdf' ??Actually, I want to mail the documents which were uploaded by various users in the contact-us form to sss@mail.com only.

Comment: @suresh `test.pdf` is a file name, you have to replace with your document name

Comment: You can also do like this: `def contact_email(contact_page)
     @contact_page = contact_page
        attachments["#{@contact_page.document_file_name}"] = File.read("#{@contact_page.document.path}")
           mail(from: 'sss@mail.com', subject: 'Recieved A Contact Enquery')
 end`

Comment: Thank you, File.read("#{@contact_page.document.path}") worked .