# Adding attachments in mailboxer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My user model already mounts an uploader, so users can upload photos for their profile. How should I add attachments to mailboxer messages then?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097522/how-to-send-the-pdf-file-uploaded-in-the-contact-form-as-an-attachment-to-the-ma/45097850#45097850

Comment: My messaging system doesn't use email addresses it uses the name field from the users table I'm looking at that but having a hard time putting it into perspective